# Installing/Registering vue component in Sails App

Tags: vue.js, sails.js

I'm trying to register a vue component (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-numeric) in a sails app. there is provision to create a new component using `parasails.registerComponent` but not sure how to include an existing one. I'm using Sails version 1.1 and the included version of Vue.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54239285/5118339).

However, I guess you might want to install a component that has dependent components in turn, and this is not trivial.
The issue is open on GitHub and these are the best answers I got so far:

1. [Register each component](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4475#issuecomment-465453694)
2. or, [include the component as an already compiled bundle](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4475#issuecomment-486466792)