# How to import and use a regular vuejs component in sailsjs?

Tags: sails.js

I need to use a vue component packages as npm module with sails.

Tried everything:

- can't import it into the page instance, import not allowed there;
- can't import it into a parasails.registerCompnent, same error;
- require also not working;
- importing it in the main app.js doesn't serve.

Looked everywhere, it is terribly frustrating, no information anywhere.

It is one of the moments I regret choosing sails for my project.

Anyone having a working example of how to use a npm pachages vue component in a sails instance page?

Answer (score 7):

From what I can tell, you can't import in the component as a package.  What you need to do is to put the contents of the .Vue file into a parasails.registerComponent file.  Use one of the existing components in the assests/js/components folder as a guide.  You may need to do some fiddling.

As an example, I took: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/grid-component.html

I placed the following in welcome.ejs

```
<!-- component template -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="grid-template">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="key in columns"
          @click="sortBy(key)"
          :class="{ active: sortKey == key }">
          {{key}}
          <span class="arrow" :class="sortOrders[key] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'">
          </span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="entry in filteredData">
        <td v-for="key in columns">
          {{entry[key]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>

<!-- demo root element -->
  <demo-grid
    :data="gridData"
    :columns="gridColumns"
    :filter-key="searchQuery">
  </demo-grid>
```

I dropped the search bar and capitalize filter to simplify this example (and to get it working).

I added to data section in welcome.page.js

```
    index: 0,
    entry: 0,
    key: 0,
    searchQuery: '',
    gridColumns: ['name', 'power'],
    gridData: [
      { name: 'Chuck Norris', power: Infinity },
      { name: 'Bruce Lee', power: 9000 },
      { name: 'Jackie Chan', power: 7000 },
      { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },
    ],
```

index, entry and key are variables used in the template.  They have to be defined in the data section or you get an undefined error.

I then created the grid.component.js file

```
parasails.registerComponent('demo-grid', {
  //  ╔═╗╦═╗╔═╗╔═╗╔═╗
  //  ╠═╝╠╦╝║ ║╠═╝╚═╗
  //  ╩  ╩╚═╚═╝╩  ╚═╝
  props: [
    'data',
    'columns', 
    'filterKey', 
  ],

  //  ╦╔╗╔╦╔╦╗╦╔═╗╦    ╔═╗╔╦╗╔═╗╔╦╗╔═╗
  //  ║║║║║ ║ ║╠═╣║    ╚═╗ ║ ╠═╣ ║ ║╣
  //  ╩╝╚╝╩ ╩ ╩╩ ╩╩═╝  ╚═╝ ╩ ╩ ╩ ╩ ╚═╝
  data: function (){
    var sortOrders = {}
    this.columns.forEach(function (key) {
      sortOrders[key] = 1
    })
    return {
      sortKey: '',
      sortOrders: sortOrders
    }
  },

  //  ╦ ╦╔╦╗╔╦╗╦
  //  ╠═╣ ║ ║║║║
  //  ╩ ╩ ╩ ╩ ╩╩═╝
  template: '#grid-template',

  //  ╦  ╦╔═╗╔═╗╔═╗╦ ╦╔═╗╦  ╔═╗
  //  ║  ║╠╣ ║╣ ║  ╚╦╝║  ║  ║╣
  //  ╩═╝╩╚  ╚═╝╚═╝ ╩ ╚═╝╩═╝╚═╝
  beforeMount: function() {

  },

  mounted: function(){
  },
  // ^Note that there is no `beforeDestroy()` lifecycle callback in this
  // component. This is on purpose, since the timing vs. `leave()` gets tricky.

  computed: {
    filteredData: function () {
      var sortKey = this.sortKey
      var filterKey = this.filterKey && this.filterKey.toLowerCase()
      var order = this.sortOrders[sortKey] || 1
      var data = this.data
      if (filterKey) {
        data = data.filter(function (row) {
          return Object.keys(row).some(function (key) {
            return String(row[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey) > -1
          })
        })
      }
      if (sortKey) {
        data = data.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
          a = a[sortKey]
          b = b[sortKey]
          return (a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1) * order
        })
      }
      return data
    }
  },

  //  ╦╔╗╔╔╦╗╔═╗╦═╗╔═╗╔═╗╔╦╗╦╔═╗╔╗╔╔═╗
  //  ║║║║ ║ ║╣ ╠╦╝╠═╣║   ║ ║║ ║║║║╚═╗
  //  ╩╝╚╝ ╩ ╚═╝╩╚═╩ ╩╚═╝ ╩ ╩╚═╝╝╚╝╚═╝
  methods: {

    sortBy: function (key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
    }
  }

});
```

Notice how the props section formatting is different from in the .Vue file of the original. Also I dropped the filter section.

I put the css in the welcome.less file

```
body {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid #42b983;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

th {
  background-color: #42b983;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.66);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

td {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

th, td {
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

th.active {
  color: #fff;
}

th.active .arrow {
  opacity: 1;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.66;
}

.arrow.asc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}

.arrow.dsc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
}
```

I've had success with several other components.  There is some trial and error and I had to remove some functions from some of the components.  If you really need to get a part going, you have the parasails source code in your project, dig in and add the abilities you need.  Then submit the changes.

Comment: thank you for taking the time for such an elaborate answer.
I did figure it out to a point by reading the parasails.js and maybe I didn't fully explained explained my problem.
You're right, we can import this way a single page component but what I really meant was how do we do it with a component package e.g one that contains multiple directories and files.

Comment: Right, I'm new to both Vue and Quasar, but am failing miserably at simply getting the plugin to work - duplicating the source of Quasar and QCalendar seems a bit ridiculous, to be frank.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest another aproach:

1. Just install Vue 2/3 and change its vue.config.js file to save build-distributable version of your Vue App into Sails App /assets directory.
2. Start developing your Vue App and keep doing it until having something to test.
3. Change Sails App /view/layouts/layout.ejs to redirect to that /assets/index.html generated by Vue compilation.

The Sails.js framework will render layout.ejs and generate a layout.html that will redirect to your brand new Vue App index page.

*Note:*

Sails will protected itself against unauthorized requests from browsers by checking /config/policies.js file! Do change it to grant free access or to establish another authentication method like Basic Authentication or JWT to control it.

Comment: by the way, if you're using Vue3 with Typescript the file to change is 'vite.config.ts'